# Trigger a Pull Request after Sprint End in jira

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm working with Jira Server and Bitbucket Server and i'm wondering if it's possible to trigger a Pull Request automatically after a Sprint has ended ?

Comment: what do you mean by "push"? Can you describe in more details what "git commands" you want JIRA to run?

Normally you push from your "local" repo to a remote "repo", jira should not be able to run commands on your local repository.

Comment: Actually it's a pull request that i want to trigger after a sprint is closed

Comment: That makes sense. Do you also have Bamboo in your atlassian suite by any chance (then I may be able to give you immediate tips)? Else, do let me know which version of Jira and Bitbucket you are using and I will try to play around with it

Comment: No i don't have bamboo , the versions : Bitbucket 5.5.0 && Jira 7.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can script behaviour like this using an add-on like [Script Runner for jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview).

It allows you, for example, to add custom scripts that respond to jira events, or that get executed as part of a workflow transition. From your script you can call [Bitbucket's REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests#post). The Script Runner [documentation is available here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/listeners.html#_jira_software_events).

There is also a [Script Runner add-on for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.stash.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview). Depending on your needs, this might make things easier to implement.